# clicking on *.py files and opening spyder ide on windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

Trying to open *.py files with spyder when clicking on them on windows 10.  I have a short cut to spyder with the target E:\python\pythonw.exe E:\python\cwp.py E:\python E:\python\pythonw.exe E:\python\Scripts\spyder-script.py  this opens spyder in a cmd window but not when I try to associate "open with" and use that as the name.  Can someone provide detailed instructions on how to do this?  I've also tried ftype Python.File=ftype Python.File="E:\python\pythonw.exe" "E:\python\cwp.py" "E:\python" "%1" "E:\python\pythonw.exe" "E:\python\Scripts\spyder-script.py"  and then did assoc .py=Python.File  but that didn't work either.  If this is the wrong place to post please advise.